# Merge 2 XML files without duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am very new to XSLT and need to merge 2 XML files without duplicating the email addresses.

I have managed to output both files on 1 XML file by loading file2 like this, although to achieve that I had to manually an element 'userlist' on file1 for it to load into:

```
<!-- Load in the 2nd file, user-list.xml -->
  <xsl:variable name="userlist" select="doc('user-list.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="userlist">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$userlist"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

and this is how it looks where the 2 files join in the output:

```
</entry>
   <entry>
      <firstname>Endeavour</firstname>
      <lastname>Morse</lastname>
      <email>morse@tvalley.co.uk</email>
   </entry>
   <users>
      <user>
         <forename>Joe</forename>
         <surname>Bloggs</surname>
         <email>j.bloggs@sample.co.uk</email>
      </user>
      <user>
```

but then when I try to do any processing on file2, it doesn't seem to recognise the match. Eg this does nothing:

```
<!-- swap the word 'users' for the word 'list' - doesn't work -->
  <xsl:template match="users">
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </list>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am using version 2.0. Any help would be very appreciated

These are extracts from the 2 XML files to be merged before any format editing:

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE users SYSTEM "user-list.dtd">
<users>
    <user>
        <forename>Joe</forename>
        <surname>Bloggs</surname>
        <email>j.bloggs@sample.co.uk</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <forename>Winston</forename>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <email>w.smith@airstripOne.gov</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mailingList SYSTEM "mailing-list.dtd">
<mailingList>
    <subscriber familyname="Smith"
                givenname="John"
                email="j.s@somewhere.com"/>
    <subscriber givenname="Luke"
                familyname="Skyw"
                email="sov@tatooine.com"/>
<userlist/>
</mailingList>
```

Comment: Please share your two xml-files as well

Comment: Hi Siebe, I have added the two original XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- 
    Load in the 2nd file, user-list.xml and select the subscriber-elements.
    An alternative would be to select here the document-node() 
    like you did and to use:
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$subscriberList/*/subscriber"/> 
    inside the <xsl:template match="users">
  -->  
  <xsl:variable name="subscriberList" select="doc('user-list.xml')/*/subscriber"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="users">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
      <!-- Apply here the variable from the second xml file -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$subscriberList"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- And match here on the subscriber elements to create the user- -->
  <xsl:template match="subscriber">
    <user>
      <forename><xsl:value-of select="@givenname"/></forename>
      <surname><xsl:value-of select="@familyname"/></surname>
      <email><xsl:value-of select="@email"/></email>
    </user>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
   <user>
      <forename>Joe</forename>
      <surname>Bloggs</surname>
      <email>j.bloggs@sample.co.uk</email>
   </user>
   <user>
      <forename>Winston</forename>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
      <email>w.smith@airstripOne.gov</email>
   </user>
   <user>
      <forename>John</forename>
      <surname>Smith</surname>
      <email>j.s@somewhere.com</email>
   </user>
   <user>
      <forename>Luke</forename>
      <surname>Skyw</surname>
      <email>sov@tatooine.com</email>
   </user>
</users>
```